# Type Compatibility Between 2 Projects using same WSDL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I have the following

**ProjectA** - has a helper method I'm creating to accept a wsdl generated type (.csproj is based on .NET 2.0 becaue it has to be for our legacy code)

**ProjectAIntegrationTests** (.csproj is based on .NET 4.5)

I've added a service reference to our WCF service to both projects in order to use it since I want to create a helper method in projectA that my Integration tests will test.  I intend to send in a

Example:

**ProjectA** - contains a helper method to allow me to send in a request and get a response

the type I send in is a proxy instance of the type or at least that's my intention in how to do this.

```
using OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.Integration.Tests.PaymentService

namespace EventInventory.TicketPoint.Payment
{
    public static class HttpClientHelper
    {
        public static PreAuthorizeResponse SendHttpRequest(PreAuthorizeRequest authorizationRequest)
        {
            PreAuthorizeResponse response;
            var service = new PaymentService.PaymentService();
            response = service.PreAuthorize(authorizationRequest);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectAIntegrationTests** - Related Integration Test from

```
using System;
using OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.PaymentService;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.Integration.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class HttpClientHelperTests
    {
        ...
        [TestMethod]
        public void SendRequest_PreAuthorizatoinWithMinimumValues_ReturnsAuthorizationRespones()
        {
            // Arrange
            PaymentsClient serviceClient = new PaymentsClient(); // proxy client from wsdl
            ... more code
            var preAuthorizeRequest = CreatePreAuthorizeRequest(transactionData, _merchantReference, _securityToken);

            // Act
            PreAuthorizeResponse preAuthorizeResponse = HttpClientHelper.SendHttpRequest(preAuthorizeRequest);

            // Assert

        }
```

**The error I get is** it's not recognizing the PreAuthorizationRequest instance I'm sending into HttpClientHelper.SendHttpReques() saying the following: `"OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.Integration.Tests.PaymentService.PreAuthorizationRequest is not assignable to OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.PaymentService.PreAuthorizationRequest"`

so the types are incompatible.

`OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.Integration.Tests.PaymentService.PreAuthorizationRequest` is not a `OurCompany.SomeAppName1.Payment.PaymentService.PreAuthorizationRequest` according to .NET

Notice the only thing I can figure different here are the namespaces behind the service.  I don't know if that matters but feels like it may be the problem, not sure.  If that's true then you can't share client proxy types across projects?  Each project is gonna have their own namespace that's specific to that project.  My second projet has Integration.Tests in the namespace.

maybe this is a cross boundary thing also that plays into effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see your proxy classes as totally different classes. Even if two classes have the same name and are identical (because they were generated from the same wsdl), it doesn't mean you can use an object of type namespace1.ServiceClient where a namespace2.ServiceClient is needed.

Normally, once you add a reference of ProjectA to ProjectAIntegrationTests, you will be able to use the service reference generated code in ProjectAIntegrationTests too. You don't need to add a new service reference on ProjectAIntegrationTests project.

You will also need to add an App.Config on ProjectAIntegrationTests and add there the configuration that you need to access the service (you can copy the necessary configuration from ProjectA).